# Database push in Firebase not working in android if i close my app, firebase bug

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int RC_PHOTO_PICKER = 2;
    private String mUsername;

    // Firebase instance variables
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private FirebaseStorage mFirebaseStorage;
    private StorageReference mChatPhotosStorageReference;

    private SeekBar seekBar;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
    VideoAdapter videoAdapter;
    List<Video> videoList;


    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog;
    EditText input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingactionbutton);
        videoList = new ArrayList();
        // Initialize Firebase components
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("videomessages");
        mChatPhotosStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("videos");

        mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    onSignedInInitialize(user.getDisplayName());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    onSignedOutCleanup();
                    startActivityForResult(
                            AuthUI.getInstance()
                                    .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                                    .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                                    .setProviders(
                                            AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER,
                                            AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                                    .build(),
                            RC_SIGN_IN);
                }
            }
        };





        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("video/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), RC_PHOTO_PICKER);


            }
        });


        attachDatabaseReadListener();
 }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Sign-in succeeded, set up the UI
                Toast.makeText(this, "Signed in!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Sign in was canceled by the user, finish the activity
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sign in canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == RC_PHOTO_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            final Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            String uriString = selectedImageUri.toString();
            File myFile = new File(uriString);
            String path = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
            String displayName = null;

            if (uriString.startsWith("content://")) {
                Cursor cursor = null;
                try {
                    cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(selectedImageUri, null, null, null, null);
                    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    }
                } finally {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            } else if (uriString.startsWith("file://")) {
                displayName = myFile.getName();
            }

            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Upload");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Enter Name");

            input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            input.setLayoutParams(lp);
            input.setText(displayName);
            alertDialog.setView(input);

            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                            new MyAsyncTask().execute(selectedImageUri);

                        }});

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.show();



        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mAuthStateListener != null) {
            mFirebaseAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
    }

    private void onSignedInInitialize(String username) {
        mUsername = username;
        attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }

    private void onSignedOutCleanup() {
        mUsername = ANONYMOUS;

    }

    private void attachDatabaseReadListener() {

        mMessagesDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                videoList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Video postSnapshotValue = postSnapshot.getValue(Video.class);
                    if (!videoList.contains(postSnapshotValue)) {
                        videoList.add(postSnapshotValue);
                        Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + videoList);
                    }

                }

                videoAdapter = new VideoAdapter(videoList, MainActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));

                recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
    }


    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Uri... params) {
            final StorageReference photoRef = mChatPhotosStorageReference.child(params[0].getLastPathSegment());
            alertDialog.setView(input);

                photoRef.putFile(params[0])
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                            // When the image has successfully uploaded, we get its download URL
                                            //  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                                            //String nameUrl=taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getName();

                                            Video video = new Video(input.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUrl.toString());
                                            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: Video Uploaded");
                                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video);
                                         //   mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video.getVideoUrl());

                                        }
                                    }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                                    int  progress = (int) ((100 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());

                                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);

                                    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                            .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                                            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                            .setContentText("Upload in progress")
                                            .setContentIntent(contentIntent(getApplicationContext()))
                                            .setAutoCancel(true);

                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                                        notificationBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                                    }

                                    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                                            getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                                    for (int incr = progress; incr <= 100; incr += 5) {


                                        notificationBuilder.setProgress(100, progress, false);

                                        notificationManager.notify(20, notificationBuilder.build());

                                    }
                                    if(progress>=100){
                                        notificationBuilder.setContentText("Upload complete").setProgress(0, 0, false);
                                        notificationManager.notify(20, notificationBuilder.build());

                                    }



                                }
                            });




           return null;
        }


    }

    private PendingIntent contentIntent(Context context) {

        Intent startActivityIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context,
                0,
                startActivityIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }





}
```

I am uploading a video to firebase storage on click of floating action button.The video gets uploaded to storage successfully.When the video is uploaded, I push the video name and its download url to database by using foll code

```
Video video = new Video(input.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUrl.toString());
                                            Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: Video Uploaded");
                                            mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video);
```

I guess this is a bug in `firebase`.I am not sure but please hear me out.
First case:
When i upload my video to `firebase` and keep my app open till the video is uploaded,the video name and download `url` are pushed to `firebase` database and video is uploaded to storage.
Second case:
If i upload a video to `firebase` storage and open other app for e.g `youtube` and in my notification, i am notified of how much the video is uploaded and after complete video is uploaded,whether i open my app again or not,`firebase` does not push the name and video url to database but video is uploaded to storage.
Why this behaviour?Can anybody please guide me..

Comment: For the second (failure) case, do you see the logcat message `onSuccess: Video Uploaded`?

Comment: @BobSnyder yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

You are using an activity-scoped success listener on `photoRef.putFile(params[0])`. [The documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnSuccessListener(android.app.Activity,%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener%3C?%20super%20TResult%3E)) explains:

> The listener will be automatically removed during onStop()

When your activity goes to the background, it is stopped and the listener is removed.  Use the other form of `addOnSuccessListener()` that does not take an Activity as the first argument.

---

Add a completion listener to the suspect `setValue()`.  Also, log the value of `input`.  I'm not sure what happens to the state of UI objects when the activity is stopped.

```
Video video = new Video(input.getText().toString().trim(),downloadUrl.toString());
Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: Video Uploaded= " + input.getText());
mMessagesDatabaseReference.push().setValue(video, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
        if (databaseError == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: SUCCESS");
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: FAILED ", databaseError.toException());
        }
    }
});
```

Based on responses to comments, it sounds like your activity may be getting destroyed (rather than stopped) when it is put into the background.  Add this method and log statement to your activity to see if that is happening:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
}
```

Comment: @BobSynder  After adding your code in my project,same thing happens.If i start the upload,keeping my app open i am able to see Log.i(TAG, "onSuccess: Video Uploaded= " + input.getText());,video is uploaded and value is pushed to database.If i close my app while uploading i am not able to see any log statements though video is uploaded to firebase storage but no value is pushed to database

Comment: When you say "close my app" do you mean you put it in the background, for example by going to the home screen?  In that case, you should continue to see log output from the app.  You indicated in a previous response, that you see the `onSuccess: Video Uploaded` log message when the app is closed.  Is that right?

Comment: "close my app" means i am putting it in background or i am closing my app.I am not able to see onSuccess: Video Uploaded if app is put in background or closed.

Comment: Add the `onDestroy()` method as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Log.i of onDestroy is never called when my app is in background

Comment: Dude you're God.Thanks alot